# Meaning of @-sign in GUI definition of a shape?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

For instance, in the [Lessphic Tutorial](http://piumarta.com/software/cola/canvas.pdf) (page 6), the following is written:

```
aShape := ShapedView withShape: (0@0 corner: 100@100).
aShape := (0@0 corner: 100@100) shapedView.
```

What does “@” mean? Is it a point with x and y coordinates? This notation perhaps originated in morphic. But “@-sign” is difficult to google.

Comment: Yes, is a `Point`. Note also that you don't need to google it. Just look for implementors of it, or debug the expression `0 @ 0`, and you will get the idea.

Comment: It did not originate in Morphic but well before, it was already in Smalltalk-80.

Comment: @Leandro Caniglia Fantasitc! Would you write a one line answer? So I can accept and close the answered question? Thx.

Comment: @aka.nice Thanks! I really come from a different community and there is a lot to learn for me. Do you also know where the 2 by 3 matrix transform, e.g., 'matrixTransform2x3' originated from? It's also noted in the  Lessphic Tutorial (linked above). (I mean I know it's basic linear algebra, but anyways.)

Comment: @mrsteve no, the transform matrices are not in "classic" Smalltalk. They seem an artifact from this framework. However, Matrix is most of the Smalltalks too, to represent a 2D matrix. And the transform matrices sure are to perform the coordinate operations translate and rotate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though one might be confused by the use of symbols like `@`, `+`, `=`, etc., and think of them as *reserved* (i.e., known to the compiler), in Smalltalk all of them are selectors of regular methods. In other words, they are not reserved tokens but valid selectors of messages that (in most of the cases) implement the expected behavior.

In the particular case of `@`, if we search for implementors we will find one in `Number`, usually implemented as

```
@ aNumber
  ^Point x: self y: aNumber
```

(In Pharo, however, there is a primitive for speeding things up, which is not needed otherwise)

The reason for this message is to provide a less verbose `Point` creation method, so that the client only has to write, say `200 @ 300`, instead of `Point x: 200 y: 300`.

Note by the way that this pattern is pretty common in Smalltalk. Some few questions ago in this [smalltalk] tag we discussed the message `/` which is a shortcut of the same sort: `2 / 3` is equivalent to `(Fraction numerator: 2 denominator: 3) reduced`. Other examples include `'hello world' readStream` for `ReadStream on: 'hello world'`, `'234.5' asNumber` for `Number readFromString: '234.5'`, etc., etc.